# Adding Price to toppings

Tags: java

So I have an assignment, and I've created the majority of the code for it, but I can't figure out how to add prices to the toppings. This is not my main code, this is for the price for the size of the pizza, but I am also required to add more of a price to the toppings. I need to add two separate prices, one for a medium sized pizza and one for a large pizza.

```
package assignment1;

public class Pizza {

private int diam;
private int numOfPizza;
private double price;
private String toppings;

Pizza(int size, String input) {
 diam = size;
 toppings = input;

}

public int getDiameter(){
    return diam;
}
public int getPizzaCount(){
    return numOfPizza;
}
public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
public String getToppings(){
    return toppings;
}
public void setDiameter(int size){
if (size == 12)
    diam = 12;
else if ( size == 16)
    diam = 16;
else
    diam = 0;
}    
public void setPizzaCount(int pizzaCount){
    numOfPizza = pizzaCount;
}
public void setPrice(double total){
    price = total;
}  
public void setToppings(String input){
    if ("Ham".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
        toppings = "Ham";
    else if ("Mozarella".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
        toppings = "Mozarella" ;
    else if ("Olives".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
        toppings = "Olives";
    else if ("Pineapple".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
        toppings = "Pineapple";
    else if ("Spinach".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
        toppings = "Spinach";
    else 
        toppings = "Plain";
}
private double calculatePrice(int size, String input){
    int total;
    if(!(toppings).equalsIgnoreCase("plain")) {
        total = 1;
    } else {
        total = 0;
    }

    if(size == 12) {
        total += 4.00;
    }

    else if(size == 16) {
        total += 5.00;
    }

    return total;
} 
    public String toString(){
        String pizzaString ="You have ordered a "+diam + " inch pizza with 
"+toppings +" toppings and a price of £"+ calculatePrice(diam, toppings);
        return pizzaString;
    }
}
```

Comment: In `calculatePrice` you should repeat the same `if-elseif` you have in the `setToppings` method, adding different prices based on the topping name. You can also use a `switch` instead, which is a bit more clear to read. You can also use a map with the topping name as key and the price as value, but a `switch` is just fine. Ah, by the way it's Mo**zz**arella :)

Comment: But more important for this site -- if you *post* a question you should *ask* an actual question. You've just posted code and a broad requirement and that doesn't fulfill the quality standards of this site. Please go through the "how to ask" subsection in the [help] to see more about how this site works and how to ask questions that get appreciation and answers.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could create something like this, setting the price to each topping. Initialise the total first and then increment the total depending on the toppings you add.

```
private double calculatePrice(int size, String input){
int total = 0;

if (toppings == "Ham")
{
    total = total + 2;
}

else if (toppings == "Olives")
{
    total = total + 3;
}

return total;
}
```